# is it possible to protect a directory using nginx confs + a php authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, nginx

Consider I am a wordpress developer and I have designed 10 wordpress theme,  also I developed some php apps using codeigniter. I uploaded a demo of each item under the /demo directory of my website on my server which http is served via nginex on it.

And I do not want my demoes be publicly available due to some policies. If a customer needs a demo I want to provide a username & passcode which after providing that any how demoes will be available for 2 hours for the customer.

First I want to know is it possible to combine nginx access to execute files with a php authentication code/file?

Next please tell me if there's other solution to my problem.

Comment: For e.g /demo/wp1 /demo/wp2 .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to generate a .htpassword file (as you word for HTTP Authentication with Apache) and then you need to modify your nginx config file as follows...

`location /secretarea {
    auth_basic "Protected Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/secretplace/.htpasswd;
}`

If you want to protect the root area just use / instead of /secretarea.